# Create entity in DTO to entity conversion

Tags: java, rest

My Rest API consumes a json dto. I now want to convert it to the corresponding entity.

Is it bad practice if I persist the entity in the conversion process (check if it exists and if not, create and return created, otherwise return existing entity)?

Background of this consideration is, that I have complex DTOs with nested DTOs and it would get really ugly if I check/create all nested DTOs on the creation of the main DTO. And I want to separate these concerns so to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can just define DTO field you want and de-serialize. It is not necessary to use all fields.
You can also use JSONObject to find your required field based on key.

Comment: Yes I do that. The main question is whether it is bad practice to persist the entity in the conversion process or not.

Comment: I don't think it is a bad practice, Unless your application tightly coupled(DB tables etc)